# Shorten up Jquery condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, optimization

I have a question about how I can shorten a Jquery if statement. In my form I have several fields that I check if they are filled. I know there are several plugins to do that for me, but I wan't to learn it by myself (with some help of others ;-))

I got this check

```
//---- First define hasError
var hasError = false;
//---- Get the value from the inputfield
var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
//---- Do the check
if(firstname == ''){
 $("#error_firstname").show();
 hasError = true;
}else{
 $("#error_firstname").hide();
}
```

I thought I could write it like this:

```
(firstname == '') ? $(".firstname").show(): $(".firstname").hide();
```

And this works, but I can't put the **hasError=true** in it, so I can't ask this in the end

```
if(hasError != false) {
 //---- if error, don't refresh page and show errors
 return false;
}else{
 //---- Save values to DB and show succes message
}
```

Anybody got an idea?

Tnx in advance

Grtzz

Wim

Answer (score 8):

To start, refactor it to a function so that you can reuse it for all fields.

Example:

```
function check(fieldname) {
    var value = $('#' + fieldname).val();
    var error = $('#error_' + fieldname);
    if (value == '') {
        error.show();
        $.hasError = true;
    } else {
        error.hide();
    }
}
```

so that you can use it as follows:

```
check('firstname');
check('lastname');
// etc..
```

Of course you can refactor that again further by storing all names in an array or just by getting `$(':input')` and calling `check()` in a loop. You keep busy refactoring ;) You can eventually take a look how existing form validation plugins do it. For example the [jQuery Validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator).

Whole point is: don't duplicate code. Refactor it.

Comment: +1 for including link to the jQuery validation plugin.  Using this plugin (if possible) would be the sensible choice.

Comment: Hi BalusC, tnx for your answer. You started me do do some big thinking about how I want to set up my validation. I think I take your way!!!!

Comment: @tvanfosson: I know it may be smarter to use the plugin. But If I alsways use plugins, I don't learn hwo to write my own code ;-)

Comment: @Wim Selles -- trust me, you'll find plenty of opportunities to write your own code: event handlers, extending plugins -- say with custom validation rules, etc.  No need to duplicate an excellent, already existing plugin, unless you are doing it purely as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can set callback for jQuery `show()` and `hide()` methods:

```
(firstname == '') ? $(".firstname").show(function(){ hasError = true; }): $(".firstname").hide();
```

Comment: Hi Rochal
Tnx for the quick answer, I'll try your answer, but BalusC started me to do some big thinking, and I think I go for his answer. But tnx again!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would have recommend you to use [JQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin but I'll take it that you want to learn it the 'hard' way. :P

Have the error messages adopt the same class e.g. "error"

```
<span class="error" id="err_firstname">...</span>
<span class="error" id="err_lastname">...</span>
<span class="error" id="err_email">...</span>
```

If any of the `span.error:visible` has at least one item, then `hasError = true`

```
 $("span.error:visible").each(function (i) {
    hasError = true;
    return;
  });
```

The hasError flag check can be shortened too:

```
if(hasError) {

 //---- if error, don't refresh page and show errors

 return false;
}
else {

 //---- Save values to DB and show succes message

}
```

Comment: I know it may be smarter to use the plugin. But If I alsways use plugins, I don't learn hwo to write my own code ;-)